# JSON API: Performing a Simple Upload UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file to Google Cloud API. As client libraries for google drive are not compatible with UWP and do not allow to perform project build in release version for 64x apps, I am trying to use JSON API and make upload by POST request by following steps [in this article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload). But problem is that file, which has been uploaded, is 0 MB size and doesn't contain any information.

Response:

```
"kind": "storage#object",
"id": "[bucketname]/6c2b78ef-be4d-46b1-a641- 
 aab3eb5ee403.pdf/[generationId]",
"selfLink": 
"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[bucketname]/o/6c2b78ef-be4d- 
46b1-a641-aab3eb5ee403.pdf",
"name": "6c2b78ef-be4d-46b1-a641-aab3eb5ee403.pdf",
"bucket": [bucketname],
"generation": [generationId],
"metageneration": "1",
"timeCreated": "2018-10-20T13:48:47.014Z",
"updated": "2018-10-20T13:48:47.014Z",
"storageClass": "MULTI_REGIONAL",
"timeStorageClassUpdated": "2018-10-20T13:48:47.014Z",
"size": "0",
"md5Hash": "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==",
"mediaLink": 
"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/[bucketname]/o/6c2b78ef- 
be4d-46b1-a641-aab3eb5ee403.pdf?generation=[generationId]&alt=media",
"crc32c": "AAAAAA==",
"etag": "CIyOyLuUld4CEAE="
```

As you can see file size is 0. When I try to open it I receive a message that file is corrupted.

Here is my C# code:

```
var destinationSource = $"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{rootBacketName}/o?key={key}&uploadType=media&name={fileName}";
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, destinationSource);
Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpRequest = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);
requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
requestMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);
requestMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are executing the request before setting its `Content`:

```
var destinationSource = $"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{rootBacketName}/o?key={key}&uploadType=media&name={fileName}";
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, destinationSource);    
requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
requestMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);
requestMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
      requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);
```

I am also using `await to wait for the request to actually complete before continuing.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake, thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!